# Getting better accuracy in iOS CLLocation

Tags: gps, coordinates, cllocationmanager, cllocation

In iOS when using CLLocationManager to get a device's coordinates the latitude and longitude are given with six decimal places after the dot. I saw an app which gives you the coordinates with thirteen decimal places. How is this possible? Changing the desiredAccuracy property did not help.

Answer (score 0):

One grade on the Earth surface is approximately 111 km. 111*10^-6 is 0.000111km, i.e. 11 cm. Most GPS receivers have the accuracy 10m. The fact that some program may display 13 digits of the fraction does not mean that the program really measured the coordinates with this precision. So, 6 digits is more than enough.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm familiar with GPS accuracy and decimal degrees accuracy, but for an experiment I'm conducting if it's possible to get more digits I'd like to get it. So you're saying with certainty that any iOS program which displays more than 6 digits doesn't get it from the OS?

Comment: How?? if your measurement tool has some fixed accuracy how can you measure the things smaller then the smallest unit of this tool?

Comment: I have no idea how they get it. Perhaps they're just throwing random digits. But if they're combining GPS with something else to give them this better accuracy that would be interesting to know.

Comment: Most likely they fool users. Or they do not understand the meaning of figures they are showing. It is not possible. 111*10^-13 == 0.000,000,000,1km == 0.0001 mm. This is not feasible with GPS technology

Answer (score 0):

But if you want to try a longer Lat & Lon, just change your floating point. i.e, this would be to the 10th decimal. Still the error will show +/- 5m.  Have fun.

```
if (currentLocation != nil) {
    _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _LongitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}
```